# How can I make a Python multithreaded pipeline use 90% of available memory?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, google-cloud-pubsub

My Python script is running in a GCE instance, with Pub/Sub as input (async pull subscription) and output.

As far as I understand, this way I can control the number of concurrent threads and, therefore limit the amount of memory used. If I set `max_messages` to 100, my script eventually runs out of memory.

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from concurrent import futures

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project, subscription_name)

def callback(message):
        print (str(message.data) + " " + str(threading.current_thread()))
        message.ack()
flow_control = pubsub_v1.types.FlowControl(max_messages=10)
executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
policy = pubsub_v1.subscriber.policy.thread.Policy(subscriber, subscription_path, executor=executor, flow_control=flow_control)
policy.open(callback)
```

It seems to me that hardcoding number of workers and messages is a primitive method of controlling memory utilization. Is there a better way to make my script allocate as many threads as VM resources allow to utilize it as efficiently as possible?

Comment: What GCE VM(resources) are you using? Did you follow any documentation? It's your own code or you based on anything? Some details about your env and possible load?

Comment: Did you consider using push subscription with Cloud Run or Cloud Functions in front of PubSub? It will scale up and down according to your PubSub traffic and therefore you will use only the required resources needed to process your messages. no waste of resources.

Comment: @PjoterS I use e2-highcpu-16 Preemptible VMs. I use "async pull" approach from GCP docs, except the `policy` thing.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Push subscription with Cloud Functions would be much more expensive and quite limited, since there are just a few pretty basic configurations for GCF resources allocation. Compute Engine is way more flexible and cheaper.

Comment: I disagree, but it's a question of point of view. With Cloud Function, you are regional high available and you haven't patch management to perform (and other admin system stuff). Yes, the CPU per hour is more expensive, but if you only take the cost of the 2 precedent items, I'm not sure that VM are cheaper!!